# Add my own query parameters to django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that uses latitude and longitude fields for location. One of the queries that I want to run using query params is search around a specific radius. I have the queryset read and I override it:

```
queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
if 'radius' in request.GET:
    queryset = queryset.in_distance(request.GET['radius'], fields=['location__latitude',location__longitude'], points=[lat, lon])
return queryset
```

When calling my admin page with `/admin/dal/listing?radius=50` I get redirected to the admin without the query string.

Followed Django's code and found this:

```
# At this point, all the parameters used by the various ListFilters
# have been removed from lookup_params, which now only contains other
# parameters passed via the query string. We now loop through the
# remaining parameters both to ensure that all the parameters are valid
# fields and to determine if at least one of them needs distinct(). If
# the lookup parameters aren't real fields, then bail out.
try:
    for key, value in lookup_params.items():
        lookup_params[key] = prepare_lookup_value(key, value)
        use_distinct = use_distinct or lookup_needs_distinct(self.lookup_opts, key)
    return filter_specs, bool(filter_specs), lookup_params, use_distinct
except FieldDoesNotExist as e:
    six.reraise(IncorrectLookupParameters, IncorrectLookupParameters(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

In a nutshell because the query string is not a known field django gracefully panics and redirect a not filter admin page.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should pop custome parameters from request. Try this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
    request.GET = request.GET.copy()
    radius = request.GET.pop('radius', None)
    if radius:
        queryset = queryset.in_distance(
            radius[0], fields=['location__latitude', 'location__longitude'],
            points=[lat, lon])
    return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but look closely at what I wrote, django removes any parameters that are not part of the model. 'radius' is not part of the model

Comment: I have solved the same problem just now. I tried to pass query params, which aren't part of the model (**number**), and had redirect to _/applabel/users/?e=1_.I added code, which i had wrote above and it's work. I refresh the page url: _/applabel/users/?number=5_, and get the right result (filtering by **number**). (Django1.11)

Comment: Once I POP the custom param, while the admin page loads fine and a more custom list (based on the query param is seen), when I click to order a column or filter via  a admin filter, the query param is not persisted (and its effects are lost). How can we solve that?